# Python using multiple conditions inside a loop

Tags: python

I am trying to use multiple conditions inside an if-else expression which is as:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td, datetime
import holidays

st_dt = '1/1/2017'
en_dt = '1/5/2017'

st_year = datetime.strptime(st_dt, "%m/%d/%Y").year
en_year = datetime.strptime(en_dt, "%m/%d/%Y").year
st_mnth = datetime.strptime(st_dt, "%m/%d/%Y").month
en_mnth = datetime.strptime(en_dt, "%m/%d/%Y").month
st_date = datetime.strptime(st_dt, "%m/%d/%Y").day
en_date = datetime.strptime(en_dt, "%m/%d/%Y").day

d1 = datetime(st_year, st_mnth, st_date, 0, 0, 0)
d2 = datetime(en_year, en_mnth, en_date, 0, 0, 0)

AllHours = []
i = 0
while(d1<=d2):
    AllHours.append(d1)
    d1 = d1 + td(hours=1)

us_holidays = holidays.UnitedStates()
HolidayWorkingDay = ['H' if x in us_holidays else 'W' for x in AllHours]
HE = [x.hour for x in AllHours]    
DayDefn = ['Type1' if (x == 'H' and y>=7 and y<=23) else 'Type2' for x in HolidayWorkingDay and for y in HE]
```

So, in the above I am trying to make sure that if certain location in the lists HolidayWorkingDay and HE meet certain criteria I give them name 'Type1' else they are 'Type2'

But it fails on the last line because of bad syntax. I am not sure what the right way to write multiple expression is

Comment: What did you intend that `and y in HE` bit at the end to do?

Comment: Where is the generator?

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions  ... especially the one with both x and y.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: `for x in HolidayWorkingDay and for y in HE` should be `for x in HolidayWorkingDay for y in HE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want nested loops you should write last list comprehension like this (without `and`):

```
DayDefn = ['Type1' if (x == 'H' and y>=7 and y<=23) else 'Type2'
           for x in HolidayWorkingDay for y in HE]
```